# Play framework route file compilation warning: local val in method at is never used

Tags: scala, playframework, compiler-flags, scalac

On my play app, I have a routes file with routes for public files. Recently I added the `-Ywarn-unused` compiler flag, and I'm getting some unexpected warnings.

Steps:

1. `activator new testingScalac` (choose play-scala from the template list)
2. Add to `build.sbt` the flag with `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Ywarn-unused")`
3. Add to the routes file:

`GET        /favicon.ico controllers.Assets.at(path="/public",file="/images/favicon.ico")`

`GET        /favicon.png controllers.Assets.at(path="/public",file="/images/favicon.png")`

`GET        /robots.txt             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public",file="robots.txt")`

Now, running `sbt compile` returns:

```
$ sbt compile
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pedrorijo/git/testRepos/testingScalac/project
[info] Set current project to testingScalac (in build file:/Users/pedrorijo/git/testRepos/testingScalac/)
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/pedrorijo/git/testRepos/testingScalac/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[warn] /Users/pedrorijo/git/testRepos/testingScalac/conf/routes:15: local val in method at is never used
[warn] GET        /favicon.ico            controllers.Assets.at(path="/public",file="/images/favicon.ico")
[warn] /Users/pedrorijo/git/testRepos/testingScalac/conf/routes:16: local val in method at is never used
[warn] GET        /favicon.png            controllers.Assets.at(path="/public",file="/images/favicon.png")
[warn] /Users/pedrorijo/git/testRepos/testingScalac/conf/routes:17: local val in method at is never used
[warn] GET        /robots.txt             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public",file="robots.txt")
[warn] three warnings found
[success] Total time: 10 s, completed Jul 5, 2016 3:11:28 PM
```

Am I doing something wrong on the routes file, or is it a playframework/compiler bug (I looked in github and couldn't find anything related to this)?

> Note: it uses play 2.5.4 but it also happens on play 2.4.x

Comment: That's a warning, not a bug

Comment: probably, even if I won't call it a bug, as it "just" raise warning

Comment: but I do use the fatal-warnings flag, which makes compilation fail with any warning.

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you to open an issue with a small project that shows the problem.

Comment: I have the same warning with play 2.5.15. Do you already have a solutions for this? And what about opening an issue on github?

Comment: @Gábor I created a bug at the time. just posted an answer with the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created an issue, it seems to be a Play framework problem: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6302

In the meanwhile a PR has been done that may fix: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/7538